# Matplotlib differentiate between mean and median with colour or shape

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, figures

I am using matplotlib version 1.4.3 and I wanted to make a Violinplot and I wanted to show the mean and the median, which is easy to do but I want to mark the mean and median so they can easily be distinguished between, by changing the colour and/or shape of one of them but I cannot see anything in the documentation that allows for that.

Anyhelp would be greatly appreciated.

```
violinplot(x, showmeans=True, showmedians=False, widths=1.0, showextrema=False)
```

Example Violinplot with means and medians:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Hint: when looking at a method's docstring never miss the `Returns` part.

```
data = np.random.weibull(1.5, size=(1000, 3))
r = plt.violinplot(dataset=data, showmeans=True, showmedians=True,
                   widths=1.0, showextrema=False)
r['cmeans'].set_color('b')
r['cmedians'].set_color('g')
```

[image]